# Trouble hosting CARTO data on GitHub

Tags: carto, carto-js, github

I'm having trouble getting data from a createLayer layer to populate a CARTO map when hosted on GitHub. The map itself draws but the [data is missing](https://chakrm.github.io/us-power-plants/), although, it works when hosted locally. Also, I am able to view data using a CARTO [vis.json](https://github.com/chakrm/ev-test/blob/gh-pages/index.html) URL hosted on GitHub. Below is the code, which is a little messy since I'm fairly new to CARTO.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem in the past and found a solution?

```
      var tableName = "powerplants_us_201603";

      // public layer in CARTO account for data queries
      var layerSource = {
        user_name: 'mishmashmaps',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [{
          sql: "SELECT * FROM " + tableName, // All power plants in dataset
          cartocss: $("#simple").text() // Simple visualization
        }]
      }

      var sublayer;

      var map_object = new L.Map('map', {
        center: [42.6526,-73.7562], // Albany
        zoom: 7
      });

      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map_object);

      cartodb.createLayer(map_object,layerSource)
        .addTo(map_object)
        .done(function(layer) {
          sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
          createSelector(sublayer);
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log("error: " + err);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The console is showing three different errors:

- First, you are loading the basemap using `http` instead of `https`.
- Then, the styles from this source (`https://carto.com/academy/css/cdbui.css`) are not loading because that file does not exist.
- Finally, the Map API is failing because an invalid error related to the CartoCSS style, concretely in this block of code: `marker-fill-opa...20               marker-type: ellipse;`.

Fix these issues, and your code should work.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick! Now I just have to go into the browser and click "load unsafe scripts" in order to view the data. It says "The page at 'https://chakrm.github.io/us-power-plants/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://mishmashmaps.carto.com/api/v1/map...' . This content should also be served over HTTPS." In order to make the script secure do I need to do something with the SQL API? [link](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/sql-api/making-calls/)

Comment: @ramiroaznar I am getting a similar issue on github, my browser is blocking the loading of: `http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css` and `http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js`.  However, these same elements load if I look at any other Carto map on the web- any idea what is going on?

Comment: You need use `createLayer` using CARTO.js HTTPS support, as explained [in CARTO documentation](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/getting-started/#https-support).